# Do you need Foundation Help Search on a SharePoint Server (MOSS) implementation?

Tags: search

We are just starting with SharePoint and will be deploying a SharePoint Server Standard Edition farm, and I was wondering if you need SharePoint Foundation Help Search?  What is this services function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing.  Are you talking about SharePoint Server 2010 or MOSS 2007?  (MOSS was renamed to SharePoint Server in 2010) If you are talking about MOSS 2007, then you would require both Office SharePoint Server Search and Windows SharePoint Services Help Search (The help search is used to search the Help content).  If you are talking about SharePoint Server 2010 Standard Edition, then you would configure Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Search Service and SharePoint Server Search (a Service Application).  The SharePoint Foundation Search Service is the Help search in 2010.

Both of the "Help" Search Services let you search the help content.